# Can I assume that the input will always be within the printable ASCII range (0x20-0x7E)?

Tags: discussion, policy

Many challenges don't specify what characters the input consists of, so I often assume the input will only consist of printable ASCII chars. Is my assumption correct?

Note that this mostly concerns string-related challenges.

Comment: You may want to include 0x10 and 0x15, Line returns.

Comment: @tuskiomi No I usually don't assume those.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

String-based challenges should always specify the valid character range, much like numeric challenges should specify the range of valid input numbers. It's even the very first thing in the [string](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string) tag wiki. I propose putting challenges on hold as unclear until the character set has been clarified.

Comment: Very rarely do I or possibly most read tag wiki...I choose to accept as general consensus, excellent!

Comment: We should honestly bump these posts to the top of the list when you search by tag.